# How can I change my own Perforce password without admin privileges?

Tags: perforce

I'm not an admin in this depot but want to change my password to something more secure. I googled it and all I'm seeing is how to reset passwords as the superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the `p4 passwd` command **with no arguments**.  It will prompt you for the old password and then the new password.